# How to check if FontFace prototype exists in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, feature-detection

I am using **FontFace** to preload fonts, it's working ok on chrome, but it stops page in Edge because FontFace is not defined in Edge.

How can I check if FontFace class prototype exists ( in JavaScript) so I don't construct it in Edge?

(I know FontFace prototype doesn't exist in Edge, but just wanted to prevent page from crashing by skipping using FontFace in Edge)

I tried this, but doesn't work in edge, it crashes.

```
if (typeof FontFace != undefined)
{
....
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `window.FontFace` or `window['FontFace']`?

Comment: I know it's doesn't exist in Edge, but just wanted to prevent page from crashing...

Comment: What @31piy told you is to check the `window`'s property. If `FontFace` is not defined in the current scope, your check will throw